# Getting error when I'm trying to get data from 3 table using sql INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql database I've 3 tables which is

1) tutor_signup_form,
2) tutor_signup_edu_psle and
3) tutor_signup_edu_olevel.

Now I'm trying to get all data from those 3 tables. But using following sql query is not working. I'm getting error message

**Sql Query I'm using.**

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . *, 
  tutor_signup_edu_olevel . * 
FROM tutor_signup_form
  INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  
  tutor_signup_form.tutor_id   ,    
  INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = 
  tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id
WHERE tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = '$tutor_id' ");
```

**Error Message:**

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
D:\software installed\xampp installed\htdocs\tutor\toplevel\edit_tutor.php on line 31
```

Comment: in your first inner join `tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  
  tutor_signup_form.tutor_id ` it should be `tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  
  tutor_signup_edu_psle.tutor_id` also not sure about the `,` in the `FROM` clause do you really need `cross join`

Comment: @MilenPavlov I used this but got nothing.

Comment: @MilenPavlov Actually I want to get all data from 3 tables.

Comment: It looks like the error might be in the PHP code, could you post the relevant part where you call mysql_fetch_array? Also, don't separate the INNER JOIN clauses with comma. And you should probably remove the whitespaces around `tutor_signup_form . *, tutor_signup_edu_psle . *, 
  tutor_signup_edu_olevel . * ` in the select statement

Comment: @jpw THAT'S THE POINT!!!

Comment: white space is not an issue. It's `,` (comma). I removed it and it's working fine. Thank You.

Comment: @Shibbir Good, I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma between the `INNER JOIN` statements:

Change this:

```
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  
tutor_signup_form.tutor_id  ,      
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = 
tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id
```

to this:

```
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_psle ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id =  
tutor_signup_form.tutor_id
INNER JOIN tutor_signup_edu_olevel ON tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = 
tutor_signup_edu_olevel.tutor_id
```